# Asking password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

bundle install

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (0.9.2.2)
Using i18n (0.6.1)

Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system Rubygems.
You can cancel this installation and run:

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
and install the bundled gems to Rubygems using sudo.

Password:

Comment: it looks like you run `bundle install` on server, where you don't have access install gems, but you could use `vendor/bundle` for it

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you install a new version of Ruby, as your system Ruby is preventing you from installing gems to it. You *can* do this using `sudo`, but it's inadvisable.

To install a new version of Ruby, I would recommend using [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install), and to manage it neatly, use [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby).